# Difference between foreach(int i.. and foreach(auto i

Tags: c++, auto

I am experimenting with C++11 features on the Clang compiler that comes with Mac OX (LLVM 4.2) and the following results puzzles me:

```
// clang compile with "c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main(void) {
    using namespace std;
    vector<int> alist={1, 2, 3, 4};

    for (int i=0; i<alist.size(); i++) {
        cout << alist[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (auto i: alist) {
        cout << alist[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Pending on the running environment, I am getting different outputs as the following:

```
1 2 3 4 
2 3 4 0
```

Why do I get different results?

Comment: Try `vector<std::string> alist = {"one", "two", "three", "four" };`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for (auto i: alist)
```

This fetches every **value** in `alist`, so `i` becomes:

```
1,2,3,4
```

You then do

```
cout << alist[i] << " ";
```

which means `alist[1]`, `alist[2]`, `alist[3]` and `alist[4]` and not the values 1, 2, 3, 4.
You should simply write :

```
cout << i << " ";
```